# Scroll in React

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I Have a React div tag below which actually holds json tree. The problem is overflow-x for horizontal scroll is not working. I am posting the code and error below.Is there any way for horizontal scroll using css in react.Vertical scroll is automatically working if mere overflow: 'scroll' is given.

```
const divStyle={
        overflow-y: 'scroll',
        border:'1px solid red',
        width:'500px',
        float: 'left',
        height:'500px',
        position:'relative'
      };

<div style={divStyle}>
                    <Droppable
                        types={['yolo']}
                        style={droppableStyle}
                        onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                        onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter.bind(this)}
                        onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave.bind(this)}>
                        <div style={{textAlign:'left', lineHeight:'100px' ,overflow:'scroll'}}>{this.state.dropped}</div>
                    </Droppable>
                </div>
```

**strong text**
 tag(parent) overflow-x if given it gives error as below.

./src/Drag.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (38:16)

36 |     render() {
  37 |       const divStyle={

> 38 |         overflow-y: 'scroll',
>        |                 ^
>     39 |         border:'1px solid red',
>     40 |         width:'500px',
>     41 |         float: 'left',

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remember that `divStyle` is an object and object keys, just like other identifier names, such as function names, etc,  cannot have dashes/hyphens unless the key is written as a string literal.

However, react recognizes only the CamelCase version, so use that instead:

```
const divStyle={
  overflowY: 'scroll',
  border:'1px solid red',
  width:'500px',
  float: 'left',
  height:'500px',
  position:'relative'
};
```

Here's a snippet from the [**official Reactjs docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

> The `style` attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM `style` JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes. For example:
>
> ```
> const divStyle = {
>   color: 'blue',
>   backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
> };
>
> function HelloWorldComponent() {
>   return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
> }
> ```

Comment: "object keys cannot have dashes/hyphens" That's [not true at all](https://codepen.io/jrunning/pen/yXJZgB?editors=0011). `style` objects in React use camelCase instead of dashes *by React convention* — for the reasons mentioned in your quotation — not because keys cannot have dashes.

Comment: @JordanRunning, true, but only if you write it as a string literal. As an identifier name though, they are not valid.

Comment: I don't dispute that, but object property keys aren't identifiers. ["A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys. A property name is a property key that is a String value."](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type).

Comment: @JordanRunning, that's great, but you don't explain why one cannot write `{overflow-y: 'scroll'}`. Care to include that?

Comment: You're right. I've rolled back my edit. It's not my place to fix your answer.

Comment: @JordanRunning, I don't get it. It seemed like such a small tweak to the explanation bit?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

`style={{overflowX : 'auto',fontSize: '14px'}}` for inline css in reactjs.

It works fine.

All styles with a dash is converted to camel case in reactjs and remove dash.